# Error: value of tuple type '(NSString, NSString)' has no member '0'

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors, tuples

I'm trying to modify some Swift source that worked perfectly fine a year ago; but since Apple released Swift 2.0, Xcode refuses point blank to run my existing code; insisting that I update it to work with the new Swift. Thanks Apple.

So, can anyone explain this utterly stupid error please?

> value of tuple type '(NSString, NSString)' has no member '0'

The failing line of code:

```
if let match = (try Filesystem.GetMounts()?.filter { 
        mapping["pattern"] != nil ? try $0.0 =~ mapping["pattern"]! : $0.0 as String == uncpath! 
    }.values.array.first) {
    ...
}
```

The GetMounts function signature:

```
class func GetMounts() throws -> [NSString:NSString]?
```

The regex operators:

```
func =~(string:NSString, regex:NSRegularExpression) -> Bool {
    let matches = regex.numberOfMatchesInString(string as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length))
    return matches > 0
}
func =~(string:NSString, pattern:NSString) throws -> Bool {
    let matches = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern as String, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators).numberOfMatchesInString(string as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length))
    return matches > 0
}
func =~(string:NSString, pattern:String) throws -> Bool {
    let matches = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern as String, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators).numberOfMatchesInString(string as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length))
    return matches > 0
}
```

Comment: You are doing faaaaar too much in one single line of code. And what is `=~` I only know of `~=`!?

Comment: Try splitting up into a few lines and move it out of the if condition. That code should be split over 3 to 5 lines.

Comment: `=~` is a helper operator I wrote because I didn't like the built-in one. Also, while splitting it across multiple lines might be a good idea, it in _no way_ helps me here. I am not asking for corrections to my programming style, I'm asking why Xcode is lying to me!

Comment: @SodAlmighty Splitting into multiple lines as well as creating a verifiable example would help you, at the very least, to get us other SO members to have an easier time attempting to help you.

Comment: Split it up into multiple lines and you will see that helps you A LOT. There are probably a few compile errors here, Xcode simply is very confused, it assumes something because you wrote something faulty and that assumption turns into that error message - split up our code and you will get a lot better error reporting.

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: Alright, that helped, thank you. I'm getting a more sensible error now, as explained in the answer below. But it still makes no sense for the compiler to report what it did, no matter how confused it might be. It _knew_ `$0` was a tuple, so why insist that it has no `.0` member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to extract the non-existant property `.values` from an array of tuples `(NSString:NSString)`. This real error is, however, obscured by complaining about `.0` members of the tuple.

E.g. the following yields the same error as you get:

```
let a: [NSString:NSString] = ["Hello":"World", "foo":"bar"]

let opt : Int? = 1
if let b = (a.filter() {
    opt != nil ? $0.0 == "Hello" : $0.0 as String == "foo"
    }.values.array.first) { // <-- actual error
        // ...
}
```

whereas the following does not:

```
let a: [NSString:NSString] = ["Hello":"World", "foo":"bar"]

let opt : Int? = 1
if let b = (a.filter() {
    opt != nil ? $0.0 == "Hello" : $0.0 as String == "foo"
    }.first) {
        print(b) // (Hello, World)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! Of course, it worked fine before Apple changed the language. What I don't understand is, why that specific error? I realise the compiler is getting confused, and so the error message might not be 100% applicable to the problem; but that _doesn't_ explain why it picked an error message that is self-evidently complete nonsense!

Comment: @SodAlmighty You might take this along with you as a rule of thumb when encountering error messages that seemingly don't make sense: functional programming, closures and chaining are all powerful tools, but it does make it tricky for the compiler to pin-point to you exactly what fails when a single line---containing a lot of operations---fails (a known "weakness" of swift compiler). Hence, if not for code readability, but for easier debugging, possibly split very complicated lines into multiple lines. Or; when you run into an error like this one for such a line: split up stuff when debugging.